# Why is my json not being parsed by Mustache?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, mustache

This is really weird. Its my first time with using the mustache library and this data works fine locally when I parse it as a raw object literal:

```
{
   "datacenters":[
      {
         "title":"Flinders St Station",
         "description":"This is a pretty major train station."
      },
      {
         "title":"Southern Cross Station",
         "description":"Did you know it used to be called Spencer St Station?"
      }
   ]
}
```

Here's the mustache template I use:

```
<script id="dinfoTpl" type="text/template"> 
    {{#datacenters}}
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <p>{{description}}</p>
    {{/datacenters}}    
</script>
```

But the moment I tuck it in a json file and try to ajax it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var data, template, html;

        $.ajax({
            url: "datacenter.json",
            success: function(data) {
                var template = $('#dinfoTpl').html();
                var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                $('#output').html(html);            
            }       
        });

</script>
```

I get an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: <template>:2

 >>         {{#datacenters}}
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
            <p>{{description}}</p>
            {{/datacenters}}    

Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'datacenters' in {
   "datacenters":[
      {
         "title":"Flinders St Station",
         "description":"This is a pretty major train station."
      },
      {
         "title":"Southern Cross Station",
         "description":"Did you know it used to be called Spencer St Station?"
      }
   ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Live code here: http://bit.ly/A17pBP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add "dataType: 'json'" to your Ajax call! I added and test it and it works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var data, template, html;

        $.ajax({
            url: "datacenter.json",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var template = $('#dinfoTpl').html();
                var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                $('#output').html(html);            
            }       
        });

</script>
```

Comment: yep. I just found that out the hard way :)